# What is the literal meaning of "Till daddy takes the t-bird away"

Tags: idioms

I first heard this in an audio-book. I do understand the implicit meaning but I always wondered what this really means and the background of this phrase.

I have tried searching the Internet but all I could find were lyrics of a song and other places where this is used.

I am not very good at English idioms, so please bear with me if I am asking something that's well known.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to come from a 1964 Beach Boys song *Fun, fun, fun*.

According to this [link](http://www.forbes.com/pictures/ehmk45megh/2-fun-fun-fun-till-her-daddy-takes-the-t-bird-away-1964-beach-boys-2/):

> This up-tempo classic suggests that life is somehow less enjoyable if one lacks access to a Thunderbird. It’s said to be based on the true story of a girl who drove her father’s car to a hamburger stand instead of the library and subsequently had her driving privileges revoked. Ford’s popular T-Bird was already in its fourth generation by then and packed a choice of V8 engines.

Comment: I'll just mention that *Ford T-Bird* is short for *Ford Thunderbird*, in case that isn't obvious.

Comment: Surely daddy was aware that life in the fast lane requires fast food?

Comment: I'm going to slightly disagree with the Forbes quote in that while the girl _thinks_ her fun is over, the narrator of the song reassures her that "... we'll have fun fun fun now that daddy took the T-Bird away". And now, wildly off-topic, but related to the song, I wonder if the German band "Kraftwerk" was taking a bit of a pun on this beach boys song, with their song _Autobahn_, which goes like this: "Wir fahr'n, fahr'n, fahr'n auf der Autobahn" https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/kraftwerk/autobahn.html